# How do I answer an incoming call on my Karbonn Smart A10?

Tags: calls, karbonn-a10

My new Christmas present is straight out the box... It's my first touch screen mobile.

I've put in my SIM and copied some of the contacts. That's it, that's all I've done. I get my first incoming call and I can't answer it - I'm tapping everywhere on the screen. I had to call the caller back once the ringing timed out.

I've read through the quick start user manual but there is no mention there.

How do I answer the call?

Comment: Every phone is different, but my first guess is you would have a "Swipe to Answer" phone, where it displays a ring/circle/object near the center of the bottom half of your screen. You would generally drag the circle to the right to answer, or to the left to decline the call.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  Your description is perfect.  It would seem that I need to go back to the shop because the circle part is rarely active:  doesn't give the red and green options and wild tapping didn't help :)  The next one should be better.  I hope!

Comment: I don't know where to comment but thanks a lot, bmdixon, for fixing up my question.  I really appreciate it and also the karbon-a10 tag. :)

Comment: @bmdixon:  please amend the typo on the tag - karbonn should have 2x"n".  I only noticed this when I search for the tag again today and it didn't come up.  Sorry if this is not the right place!  Can't see how to contact you.